# Azure Synapse STUFF with FOR

Tags: azure, t-sql, azure-synapse

I am working with a simple query in azure Synapse, however I think the FOR in the following query is not accepted in synapse :

```
select stuff((select ','+quotename(C.ClaveReferencia)
     from [Landing].[BKPF]  as C
     for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Does anybody know a workaround for that?

Comment: Why not just use `string_agg`?

Comment: just found that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

SELECT ''''+STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), ClaveReferencia), ''',''') AWKEY
FROM [Landing].[BKPF]